# Define JSON schema value os one attribute is required only if another optional filed value is present

Tags: javascript, java, json, schema

How Can I define a JSON schema wher the phone type is required only there is a value in the phone. Basically the phone value is optionsl, but if there is a value the phone type should be enum:[HOME,WORK,OFFICE], How can you achieve this?

Comment: What do you need specifically? A function to validate a given JSON? If so, please give us more details or the JSON object.

Comment: @tiagodws I am looking for JSON schema where phone type is required only if the phone number is exists. Is there a way to define the required ("phone_type") if phone number is not empty? Not the function to validate JSON. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what are you trying do achieve. JSON is a notation format, incapable of doing any validations.